# last - How to debug cpp code in eclipse che using gdbserver

Tags: docker, gdbserver, eclipse-che

I am trying to Debug c++ code in Eclipse Che as outlined in their [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/debug.html#gdb).

But I now I want to debug it using  gdbserver.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.